# What was Newton's own explanation of Newton's rings?

Tags: optics, waves, history, interference, wave-particle-duality

What was Newton's own explanation of [Newton's rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_rings)? Newton advocated a corpuscular theory of light, but his rings would most conveniently be explained by a wave theory. How did he explain his own discovery?

Comment: This question might be more appropriate at [hsm.SE].

Comment: For future reference, as per [site policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-history-of-physics-questions-be-on-topic), future questions like this one should be posted at [hsm.se].

Comment: [Corresponding post on HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/how-did-newton-explain-his-interference-rings-without-wave-optics)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Isaac Newton's own words, per Proposition XII on p. 78 of [Opticks: or, A treatise of the reflexions, refractions, inflexions and colours of light. Also two treatises of the species and magnitude of curvilinear figures.](https://archive.org/stream/opticksortreatisnewt#page/78/mode/2up/search/rings)

Published 1704.

[image: Prop. XII]

> Every ray of Light in its passage through any refracting surface is
>   put into a certain transient constitution or state, which in the
>   progress of the ray returns at equal intervals, and disposes the ray
>   at every return to be easily transmitted through the next refracting
>   surface, and between the returns to be easily reflected by it.

Comment: Yayks... if we give him a bit of leeway, he basically tried to think about the kernel of a path integral over 300 years before Dirac and Feynman. He missed that one had to consider all possible paths to make it work, of course. :-)

Comment: @Hackless: You may want to compare that against the Huygens-Fresnel principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle. One could easily implement both in a ray tracer and see how false Newton was...

Comment: Newton believed in corpuscles not waves and so his statement above is no more than a restatement of his observations rather than an explanation based on his corpuscular theory of light.

Comment: Future visitors to this post should also see [this post](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/6032/how-did-newton-explain-his-interference-rings-without-wave-optics) on HSM.SE, for more detailed context.

Comment: This literally makes no sense to me. Did Newton think that this was a clear explanation, or was he just fudging it?

Comment: You can find Newton's comments in his work on Optics. Feynman goes over this in his Physics.