# Newton's explanation for interference

Tags: optics, visible-light, soft-question, geometric-optics, history

If **Isaac Newton** believed that light is a particle, then how did he explain the interference phenomena?

Comment: I seem to recall that  no one demonstrated the interference of visible light until Newton was quite elderly. All of the ways that it can be done using basic instruments are picky and sensitive to seemingly unimportant details.

Comment: @dmckee Sounds reasonable, thanks.

Comment: It might be reasonable, but I seem to be mistaken. From the "Related" sidebar we have [What was Newton's own explanation of Newton's rings?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246015/520), which could be a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was Newton's own explanation of Newton's rings?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246015/)