# How did Newton explain the effect we now call Newton's Rings?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference, history

I'm trying to understand how Newton formulated his corpuscular theory of light when he was surrounded by evidence of light's wave-light properties. Specifically, the effect that we now call [Newton's rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_rings), which he discusses in Optiks.

Newton discusses the Rings in Part 1, Book 2 of Optiks (page 160 of [this pdf](http://brizhell.org/Newton_Speckles/Opticks%20-%20scan%20from%20original%20manuscript%20-%20I.%20Newton.pdf)), but having read it, and various other parts, I can't figure out how he jumps from the observation of refraction to the conclusion that light must be made out of corpuscles, and not a wave-like phenomena.

Comment: Duplicate [What was Newton's own explanation of Newton's rings?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/246015/)